# ElasticSearch/OpenSearch: The limit of the length of keyword field?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch/OpenSearch, so if I overlook something basic, please forgive me.

I was trying to index a super long text(like 500,000 character length), into a `keyword` type field. Before that, I increased the `ignore_above` parameter of the field to 147483647.

However, the following error occurred and indexing failed.

```
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"content\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped. Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms. The prefix of the first immense term is: '[12, 12, 12, 50, 48, 50, 50, 46, 49, 48, 10, 86, 111, 108, 46, 55, 55, 47, 78, 111, 46, 49, 49, 47, 49, 49, 48, 48, 10, 10]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 474312"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"content\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped. Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms. The prefix of the first immense term is: '[12, 12, 12, 50, 48, 50, 50, 46, 49, 48, 10, 86, 111, 108, 46, 55, 55, 47, 78, 111, 46, 49, 49, 47, 49, 49, 48, 48, 10, 10]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 474312","caused_by":{"type":"max_bytes_length_exceeded_exception","reason":"bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 474312"}},"status":400}
```

My take of this is the following:

Lucene, which works under the hood of ElasticSearch, can't process a term longer than 32766 character length. And the long sentence I tried to index into `keyword` type field is treated as one big term, because it isn't divided by tokenizer.

So, what this error message actually says is; do not index a text longer than 32766 character length into keyword field.

Is my understanding correct? I'd appreciate it if you would shed some lights on it.

Incidentally, I'm using opensearch1.2.4 on docker.

Comment: Yes it's correct. I have had the same issue. it rejects fields having text longer than 32766 characters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sharing useful information!